# How to <Link> to same page

Tags: react-router

I'm converting some existing code to use React Router.

The code currently uses `<a href="#" ...>`, which I am changing to `<Link to=??>`.

My question is: 
What should I use for the `"to"` parameter? If I use `to="#"`, the application routes to "/", which is not what I want.

It works if I use the current route name, but the whole idea of `href="#"` is that the code doesn't have to know how it is accessed.

I am using React Router 2 with history=browserHistory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using anchor tags in react-router 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4)

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few solutions that worked for me:

- `<Link to={{}}>`

  - [`to` can take an object](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link); sending an empty object stays on the current page
- `<Link to={{ search: '' }}>`

  - In my specific case, I wanted to stay on the same page but wipe the search params, which is what this does
- `<Link to={window.location.pathname}>`

  - Similar to the suggestion in [Damien Leroux's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35984274/399105) answer, without the `hash`
- `<Link to="#">`

  - This seemed to work fine for me, maybe because I'm using react-router v6

What didn't work for me:

- `<Link to={this.props.route.path}`

  - I'm using functional components, so I don't have any `this.props`. Maybe there's another way in the react-router API to get the path.
- `<Link to=".">`

  - This linked to `/` for me

Comment: This is a comprehensive answer and it worked for me. Thanks @bmaupin

Comment: Comprehensive and effective. Should be the top answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For me this was the solution:

I used the npm module `react-router-hash-link`. It is quite easy to use. [Docs here](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link)

`import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
<Link smooth to="/#services">Services</Link>`

And wrap your `<App>` component in `<HashRouter>` from npm module `react-router-dom`

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777157/5057689)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try something more or less like that:

`<Link to={window.location.pathname} hash="/#">HASH</Link>`

See there : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#hash

Comment: This does not work, but the hint to use a props parameter was a good one.  I'll give the solution in a formal "answer".  

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works because "this.props.route.path" is the route to the current page:

```
<Link to={this.props.route.path} ...
```

Note that if you have nested React components, you have to pass "this.path" down from the outer components, as described at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link to='#' />
```

this works but it will still stack your history

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
<Link className="dropdown-item" to="javascript:void()">
   Link Title
</Link>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to go to a specified section of your "/" path (even from another path), you can make it work with the anchor tag as well, like this:

`<a href="./#your-section-id">Go to Section</a>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: this does not answer the question asked. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4 does