# Click link to scroll to specific section react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have implemented a side menu that has a link tag for each section but I am unsure how to implement the functionality when clicking on them the user is taken to the specific section. I understand how to do it if the it was in the same component and if I was generating the sections in a normal fashion but I am doing it in a different way and I am unsure how to implement something like react-scroll or scrollchor.

Here I am generating the sections with buildTree by mapping over some data I have in another file.

```
export default class CheckboxGroup extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkboxState = new Map();
    this.state = {
      checkboxState: new Map(),
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    counter: PropTypes.number,
  };

  treeCheckboxOnChange = (parentLabel, id, checked) => {
    this.checkboxState = this.checkboxState.setIn([parentLabel, id], checked);
    this.setState({
      checkboxState: this.checkboxState,
    });
  };

  mapParents = (counter, child) => {
    const parentLabel = child.get('label');
    return (
      <li key={child.get('name')} className='field'>
      <SegmentHeader style={segmentStyle} title={child.get('label')} icon={child.get('icon')}>
        <div className='fields' style={zeroMargin}>
          <div className='four wide field'>
            <TreeCheckbox
              label={`Grant ${child.get('label')} Permissions`}
              parentLabel={parentLabel}
              counter={counter}
              onChange={this.treeCheckboxOnChange}
            />
            {child.get('items') && this.buildTree(child.get('items'), counter + child.get('name'), parentLabel)}
          </div>
          <div className='twelve wide field'>
            <GrantDropdown checkboxState={this.state.checkboxState.get(parentLabel, new Map())} label={child.get('label')} childItems={child.get('items')}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SegmentHeader>
    </li>
    );
  };

  mapDataArr = (counter, parentLabel) => (child) => (
    (counter === 0) ?
      this.mapParents(counter, child)
      :
      <li key={child.get('name')}>
        <TreeCheckbox label={child.get('label')} parentLabel={parentLabel} onChange={this.treeCheckboxOnChange}/>
        {child.get('items') && this.buildTree(child.get('items'), counter + child.get('name'), parentLabel)}
      </li>
  )

  buildTree = (dataArr, counter, parentLabel) => (
    <ul key={counter} style={listStyle}>
      {dataArr.map(this.mapDataArr(counter, parentLabel))}
    </ul>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='tree-view'>
        {this.buildTree(this.props.data, this.props.counter)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have used the same technique to map over the data to create my sticky sideNav.

```
export default class SideNav extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    counter: PropTypes.number,
  };

  mapPermissionNames = (counter, child) => (
    <li key={child.get('name')}>
      <Link>{child.get('label')}</Link>
    </li>
  )

  mapDataArr = (counter) => (child) => (
    (counter === 0) ?
      this.mapPermissionNames(counter, child)
      :
      <li key={child.get('name')}>
        <Link>{child.get('label')}</Link>
      </li>
  )

  buildTree = (dataArr, counter) => (
    <ul key={counter} style={listStyle}>
      {dataArr.map(this.mapDataArr(counter))}
    </ul>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='tree-view'>
        {this.buildTree(this.props.data, this.props.counter)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the parent where they both are rendered.

```
export default class LocationPermissions extends AbstractSettingsComponent {

  handlePermissionChange = (e, { value }) => {
    this.updatePerson('locationPermissions', value);
  }

  updateCheckmarks = (id, checked) => {
    const { currentPerson } = this.props;
    if (checked && !currentPerson.get('permissions').includes(id)) {
      this.updatePerson('permissions', id, true);
    } else if (!checked && currentPerson.get('permissions').includes(id)) {
      this.filterItem(['currentPerson', 'permissions'], id, 1);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { currentPerson } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <SegmentHeader icon='building' title='Location Permissions'>
          <div className='two fields' style={zeroMarginBottom}>
            <div className='field'>
              <OptionSelector
                label={`Grant ${this.getPerson()} permissions for...`}
                options={this.getPermissionOptions()}
                value={currentPerson.get('locationPermissions') || 0}
                onChange={this.handlePermissionChange}
              />
            </div>
            {currentPerson.get('locationPermissions') === 2 &&
              <div className='field'>
                <label>Grant Location Admin Permissions For</label>
                <LocationMultiSelect name='Every' {...this.props}/>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        </SegmentHeader>
        <StickyContainer>
        {currentPerson.get('locationPermissions') === 3 &&
          <div className='fields'>
            <div className='three wide field'>
              <Sticky style={{ paddingTop: '15px' }}>
                <SideNav
                  data={permissionSections}
                  counter={0}
                />
              </Sticky>
            </div>
            <div className='twelve wide field'>
            <CheckboxGroup
              data={permissionSections}
              counter={0}
              onChange={this.updateCheckmarks}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        }
        </StickyContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am having trouble understanding how to implement something like react-scroll or scrollchor or react-router link tags to be able to click on the section and scroll to that section on the page. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: This did the work for me [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777157/5057689)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to just use the browser supported way by doing:

```
<a href={`#${child.get('label')}`}>{child.get('label')}</a>
```

And then just add an id to the list element.

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I did it without complicated steps or 3rd party libraries

1- create a div with an onClick event and add the window.location.replace to replace the current URL with the desired one. here is an example

```
<div onClick={() => window.location.replace("/#about")}>
<span>go to about</span>
</div>
```

2- in your section add the Id you are trying to go.

```
<h2 id="about">About</h2>
```

and all done without 3rd party libraries. cheers.

Comment: The `onClick` on that particular `div` would force the page to reload/refresh, so in order to prevent that one can change the opening tag of that `div` to `<div onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); window.location.replace('/#about');}}>`.

Comment: when i click about link from another page this is coming back to the home page, but not going to about section. This is my code
                <li><Link 
                onClick={() =>window.location.replace('/#about')}
                  to="about"
                  offset={-80}
                  className="uk-link-reset pointer"
                >
                  Features
                </Link>
              </li>

Answer (score 8):

Used this way working fine (react js)

```
<Link to='/home/#section1'></Link>
```

and other page put a id name

```
id={'section1'}
```

Comment: This does not work. It takes to the page /home/section1 which is not defined in the routes.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

In the section you want to scroll to you'll need to add an id tag for example: 
`<div id="my-target">Hello there </div>`

Then within your list you set up the following onClick function:

```
<li
  onClick = {(e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   window.scrollTo({
   top: document.querySelector("#my-target").offsetTop,
   behavior: "smooth",
});}}>
 Go to Target
</li>
```