# How can I jump to specific parts of a Web page by using the anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, anchor

[React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) uses "#" in the URL so when I write

```html
<a href="#specificAreaId">Click here to scroll to top</a>
```

it doesn't work as scrolling to the element which has id: specificAreaId. Instead, it navigates to another page. How can I do this?

Comment: can you show code?, I just tried it and it works, check this https://jsbin.com/yawiboditu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I think that happened because I import react-router library to my code but you don't. Your solution works with me but the url still changed to 'http://abccom/#/specificAreaId'

Comment: well, you can try the other posted answers

Answer (score 0):

Create the anchor the way that is specified in *[Anchors](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)*.

Comment: Peter Mortenson, I should have just told him to use the term "NAME" instead of "HREF" - that would have been best.  Why didn't you just add that bit of detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-scrollable-anchor`

Install it:

```
npm install --save react-scrollable-anchor
```

And import it in your component:

```
import ScrollableAnchor from 'react-scrollable-anchor'
```

Then use it like:

```html
<a href='#myScrollSection'>Go to myScrollSection</a>
<ScrollableAnchor id={'myScrollSection'}>
     <div>Hello, World!</div>
</ScrollableAnchor>
```

You can read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollable-anchor).

Answer (score 0):

I am going with the assumption that you are using `hash history` in `react-router`. Try to use `browser history` instead.

Also it would be ideal if you create the anchor tags like:

```html
<a href="pageUrl#specificAreaId">Click here to scroll to top</a>
```

You could also refer this post, regarding a similar issue:

*[Use anchors with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280369/use-anchors-with-react-router)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery's 'animate scrollTop'.

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#specificAreaId').offset().top
}, 800);
```

Comment: How will it detect if the url is `http://www.example.com/#specificAreaId`?