# Auto scroll to anchor tag element in react using componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, autoscroll

- My URL

https://abc1234.com/users#api-doc

- HTML

```
    <div className={parent}>
        <div className={child}>
            {someContent}
            <a id="api-doc">Hello API</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am writing the page in ReactJS. I need to implement a way so that the page should auto-scroll down to the Hash i.e. **api-doc** but somehow it's not auto-scrolling on page load (very first time).

I tried a workaround which is like this

```
    componentDidUpdate(){
        let id = this.props.history.location.hash.replace("#", "");
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (element) {
                element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(true);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
```

It's working but I am looking for a better way to achieve the same

In other words, I do not want to use setTimeOut.

I added setTimeOut cause I found that document.getElementById(id) is giving null (very first time), I am assuming that somehow componentDidUpdate is running before the entire render. I have also used dangerouslySetInnerHTML .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `document.getElementById(id)` returns `null` because the element has not yet rendered.

With React do not use `document.getElementById()`.
React nodes are not real DOM nodes (e.g., text or element nodes) themselves, but a representation of a potential DOM node.

Instead, use the hook `useRef()` [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Create the following component.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect }  from 'react';

const myComponent = (props) => {

  const myRef = useRef();

  function scrollToComponent() {
    if (window.location.hash === '#api-doc') {
      myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
      myRef.current.focus();
    }
  }

  useEffect( () => scrollToComponent(), [] )

  return (
    <div ref={myRef} id="api-doc">
       ...
    </div>
  )
};

export default myComponent;
```

Using `useEffect` this way will (only) trigger when the component mounts. (therefore avoiding the issue of the JS running before the component has mounted)

The function I have named `scrollToComponent` will check the URL for a hash, if it passes the condition, it will scroll to the ref.

Remember to import the component to your main file.

*Note: using Link from React router may be a better solution. (but one I'm not familiar with)