# react, how to scroll child component div from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

I have react pages that are composed of sub components. I have link in footer and expected to scroll to specific div when user click on it. I have tried to hash # but its not really working. not sure how to approach this issue?

In following example I need to go `OurServicesMessage` when user click on . This link exist in `footer` component.

`child component where I need to go`

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const OurServicesMessageBanner = () =>{

 return(
    <Fragment>
        <div id="OurServicesMessage" className="service-message-banner">
            //... code
        </div>
    </Fragment>
 );
}

export default OurServicesMessageBanner;
```

`Parent component/ page`

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";

const Services = () => {

useEffect(() => {
  const hash = window.location.hash;

  if (hash === "#OurServicesMessage") {
    const element = document.getElementById("OurServicesMessage");
    if (element) {
      const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const scrollPosition = (elementRect.top + window.scrollY) + '80';
    
    window.scrollTo({
      top: scrollPosition,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
   }
  }
}, []);

return (
 <Fragment>
  <LayoutOne>
    <OurServicesParallax />
    <OurServicesMessageBanner />
    //.. remaining code
  </LayoutOne>
 </Fragment>
 );
};

export default Services;
```

`footer from where the link should scroll jump from`

```
const Footer = () => {
return(
<footer className="footer-section">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"> 
                <Widget title="Helpful Link">
                    <List classes="recent-post helpful_post">
                        <LI>
                            <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/services#OurServicesMessage"}>Our service</Link>
                        </LI>
                        //... other link codes...
                    </List>
                </Widget> 
            </div> 
    </div>
</footer>
```

`app routes`

```
export const routes = [
 { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
 { path: "/home", element: <Home /> },
 { path: "/authlogin", element: <AuthLogin /> },
 { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
 { path: "/services", element: <Services /> },
 // other paths
```

Comment: Don't add a string: `(elementRect.top + window.scrollY) + 80`

Comment: what should i add ?

Comment: the above code does took me to page but not right position

Comment: You're adding `'80'` when you probably should be adding `80`.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Well why are you adding 80 in the first place?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280369/use-anchors-with-react-router