# Using anchor tags in react-router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want the page to scroll down to my anchor tags when a user navigates to it through an anchor link.

I'm using react-router 4 and I've defined things as follows:

navbar:

```
export default (props) => {
  const { 
    updateModal,
    updateRoute,
  } = props
  return(
    <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
      <Nav>
        <NavDropdown eventKey="4" title="Solutions" id="nav-dropdown" noCaret>
          <MenuItem eventKey="4.1">
             <Link to='/solution#ipos'>TESTING ANCHOR</Link>
          </MenuItem>
...
```

some route:

```
export default class extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid className='solutions' fluid>
       <Row className='someClass'>
        <div>
          <h2><a href='ipos' id='ipos'>Ipos morna santos paros</a></h2>
          ...
```

I can see the hash anchor tag in the url and in my redux store when I click on the anchor link in the navebar, and it indeed navigates to the new route, but it doesn't scroll down to the tag itself.

Is it up to me to create the scroll function or how is it supposed to work exactly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is a known issue with react router. (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394#issuecomment-220221604)

There is a solution as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link this package solves the issue.

You have to use this `Hash Link` as the `Link` like below.

`import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';`

Comment: It is worth noting however, that this can be easily avoided by simply using a standard `<a>` link in this instance. React-Router `<Link>` is not necessary because if you are navigating in the same page there is no component manipulation that needs to happen here. Therefore a standard `<a>` link could be considered the optimal solution, it does not require another package installation etc. However if you needed to navigate to a hash link on another "page" then yes, this package would be the solution.

Answer (score 82):

To scroll down to your  anchor tags, you need to install [React Router Hash Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link), with:

```
npm install --save react-router-hash-link
```

then import Hash Link:

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
```

and then use Hash Link, for example:

```
<Link to="/pathLink#yourAnchorTag">Your link text</Link>
```

and at the destination component, for example:

```
<div id= "yourAnchorTag">
      <p>Linked to here<p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's so hard to believe that a more common practice does not exist yet outside of this package. Seems really really strange.

Comment: Reporting in Feb 2020, this is still the best way to go (sadly)

Comment: I actually can't even get this to behave as expected. This framework can be a big letdown sometimes. I have an element with a static ID that will never change, and all I want to do is add an a[href="#myAnchor"] and scroll to it. It seems like this is legitimately impossible without at least 20 lines of code.

Comment: It's also interesting to me that this SO answer is the only one that provides an example of how to write the thing you're linking to. Thanks @Adrian

Comment: Reporting April 2022, (After some research)this is still the best way to do it.

Comment: Does anyone know if npmjs.com/package/react-hash-link is better than react-router-hash-link?

Answer (score 9):

If you have only few predictable anchor links, the simplest way to achieve the normal behavior is to manually `scrollIntoView()` of the element if you have the expected anchor tag in the `Window.location.href`.

```
class Page extends react.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.$ref && location.href.includes('#my-ref')) {
            this.$ref.scrollIntoView({
                // optional params
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'start',
                inline: 'center',
            });
        }
    }

     render() {
        return (
            // This is the div you want to scroll to
            <div ref={ref => {
                this.$ref = ref;
            }}>
                Other content
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Check [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) and [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

Comment: I messed around with `<a>`, `<Link>`, and `<HashLink` and none worked right - they would all refresh the page and maybe scroll to the right place.  This just worked by scrolling to the right place minus the refresh

Comment: Very helpful, and thanks. One small correction though. The param `behaviour` should be `behavior` ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can pass an object to Link, like this

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

ref. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: This was helpful.

Comment: Updated link (heh), where they incidentally use hashes in the url (heh heh): https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#link but even more interestingly, the old `hash` property has been removed (heh heh heh?)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using hash fragments in anchor tags is to query the DOM and use `scrollIntoView()` as part of the `onClick` event.

```
function handleClick(evt) {
  ...
  document.querySelector('[id="label-input-1"]').scrollIntoView();
}

...

<a href={''} onClick={e => handleClick(e)}>Foo</a>
```

This just bypasses the routers refreshing of the page when the window location updates with the hash address.

Comment: The problem here is when you switch to another route and the dom is not completely loaded yet, the function won't find the anchor and thus will not scroll to it. You will have to wait for the component to be fully loaded

Comment: @JonasMerhej - This isn't for switching routes, but for scrolling to a location on the page without refreshing the route.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @filippo, but with React hooks and a little Typescript.

```js
import React, { Functioncomponent, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const MyFunc: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const myRef = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myRef && location.hash.includes("#my-ref")) {
      myRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
        inline: "center",
      });
    }
  }, [myRef, location.hash]);

  return (
    <>
      <div> Some stuff before </div>
      <div ref={myRef}> Scroll to me </div>
      <div> Some stuff after </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyFunc;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using Gatsby, and my solution was to use `@reach/router` in the form:

```
import { navigate } from '@reach/router';
navigate('#some-link');
```

[Link to Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation).