# Href to another page React Gatsby

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, gatsby

I have a menu with the following link:

```
<li className="nav-item" key={link.name}>
 <a href={`page-2#second-section`}>{link.name}</a>
</li>
```

But when i click it, i am taken to : 
http://localhost:8000/page-2/#second-section

but still at the top of the page instead of the middle of the page like where the div with the id:"second-section" is.

When i click it again to go to the section, the url is:

http://localhost:8000/page-2/page-2#second-section

How can i make this work?

```
<div id="first-section">
   <hr></hr>
   <SEO title="Page one" />
</div>
<div id="second-section">
   <hr></hr>
   <SEO title="Page two" />
</div>
```

when i do this dirrectly:

```
<li className="nav-item" key={link.name}>
    <a href="#second-section">{link.name}</a>
</li>
```

it works from the same page. But it doesn't work from other pages

Comment: Can you try using `<a href="/page-2#second-section">{link.name}</a>` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Page stil at the top instead of going to that div

Comment: Actually this should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4

Comment: Also you should use a `Link` (import it from `gatsby`) instead of a regular <a>

Answer (score 0):

for this kinda uses, we must use Anchorlinks
more details is available here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-anchor-links/

```
import { AnchorLink } from "gatsby-plugin-anchor-links";

export default () => (
  <AnchorLink to="/about#team" title="Our team">
    <span>Check out our team!</span>
  </AnchorLink>
);
// => <a href="/about#team" title="Our team"><span>Check out our team!</span></a>

export default () => (
  <AnchorLink to="/about#team" title="Check out our team!" />
);
// => <a href="/about#team" title="Check out our team!">Check out our team!</a>

export default () => (
  <AnchorLink
    to="/about#team"
    title="Check out our team!"
    className="stripped"
    stripHash
  />
);
// => <a href="/about" class="stripped" title="Check out our team!">Check out our team!</a>
// => Hash will be stripped, and a full page scroll will occure onRouteChange

export default () => <AnchorLink to="/about" title="About us" />;
// => <a href="/about" title="About us">About us</a>
```