# Link that jump to a certain part of a SPA that contains different components.- Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Okay, so maybe the title wasn't clear enough.

I have a website that is an extreme simple page made with Reack/Material-UI.
Starts in a Main content, if you scroll down there will be the "About us", and if you scroll even more there will be the "Contact" part.

I have a Navbar too that has the links: HOME, ABOUT US, CONTACT. 
The issue I'm having is that I want that when the user clicks the links, the page will simply scroll down to the related section.

The thing is that each of these sections are different components. The App.js that has all of them imported.

Routing doesn't work for me  because when the user clicks the links, the website won't scrolldown - instead, it will show only THAT component. How can I make it work?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [this resolved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found a easy way of doing it. 
I'm using the React scroll component that I imported.

If you guys wanna check about this package: 
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll][1]