# How can I get React helmets to work with a # href?

Tags: html, reactjs

My React Helmet works fine for the website, just not when I click on hash # hrefs redirecting to parts of the page, it goes back to 'localhost'. Any idea? Thanks legends!

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

const title = 'Title Here';
    
    
    const Home = () => {
      return (
        <Layout>
            <Helmet>
              <title>{ title }</title>
            </Helmet>
           <Section grid> 
            <Hero />
            <BgAnimation /> 
           </Section> 
          <Projects />
          <Technologies />
          <Timeline />
          <Acomplishments />
        </Layout>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

Comment: Are you using react-router? If so you can try react-router-hash-link package like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50006901/4712724

Comment: Not using react router, using next-js

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it using Head from 'next/head'. I just put:

> ```
>      <Head>
>        <title>{title}</title>
>      </Head>
> ```

inside `<NavLink>`, not sure if that's correct but it works.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from 'next/head';

const title = 'Title Here';

const Header = () =>  (
  <Container>
    <div1>
      <Link href="/">
        <a style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", color: "white", marginBottom: "20px"}}>
        <DiCssdeck size="3rem" /> <Span>Portfolio</Span>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </div1>
    <Div2>
      <li>
        <Link href=".#projects" title={title}>
          <NavLink>Projects
          <Head>
           <title>{title}</title>
         </Head>
          </NavLink>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href=".#tech">
          <NavLink>Technologies
          <Head>
           <title>{title}</title>
         </Head>
          </NavLink>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
..............
..............
```