# Navigate to a section of another page in MUI 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In my React app, I'm trying to navigate to a section of my first page when pressing a button on my Nav Bar. I'm achieving this with an onClick function on my button:

```
const onNavClick = (e, id) => {
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  e.preventDefault();
  element.scrollIntoView();
};
```

...

```
<Button
  onClick={(e) => onNavClick(e, "products")}
  ...
>
  Shop
</Button>
```

I'm also specifying an `id` on the element I want to navigate to.

Everything works as expected in the main page since that element is already in the DOM. The issue is that I can't access it when I go to another page and press the Nav button to get to that part. I'm getting this error:

`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')`

**Is there any way I can access that element from other pages and navigate to that section in my first page?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scroll to an element that doesn't exist on the page. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

> The Element interface's scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element's
> parent container such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is
> called is visible to the user.

If you want to navigate between pages, there are various options.

You can use a [Link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-link/) component from MUI:

```
<Link href='#'>Link to somewhere</Link>
```

If you're using `Next.js`, you can use their built-in [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()
router.push('/homepage')
```

Another commonly-used router is [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
let navigate = useNavigate()
navigate('/homepage')
```

If you want to navigate to the page and **then** scroll to the element, you can pass some kind of data to indicate this, and then handle it in the destination page.

Example using `Next.js`:

Pass data as a query:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()

// Pass some kind of reference to the element you want to scroll to
router.push({
    pathname: '/homepage',
    query: { scrollTo: element }
})
```

In `/pages/homepage`, check the query and handle appropriately:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()
let element
if (router.query?.scrollTo)
{
    element = router.query.scrollTo
    // Now scroll to the element
}
```

Comment: It’s actually what Id of an element used to, you can add id to the end of url you are scrolling and you will go to that id eg:  navigate(“/home#section1”)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is there a way to do the Next.js part with pure React.js?

Comment: @antokhio I tried to navigate as you said in this way `navigate(/#products)`, but it doesn't  get me to that section of the page at all. Just the whole main page.

Comment: @Nima Hi, thought that this is a native feature, and seems like this a router plugin option, check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4

Comment: @antokhio unfortunately that thread's issue is different from mine since they are navigating to an element on the same page. But I want to navigate to an element of another page.

Comment: Well this is the same for both cases, usually when you navigate on same page you use scroll to when you navigate to element on on another page you provide an anchor tag (witch is id) and you get your page open with that element in view