# React : navigate to a html tag inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

i want to go from a component to another and **slide directly to an html tag** inside of it .

using **react router v6**

```
<Route path="/mypage/#c" element = {<MyPage/>} />
```

( #c is a id of the html tag in the /mypage )

but the code i've provided isn't working .

it just goes to the page and doesn't slide into the tag .

Comment: similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223566/using-anchor-tags-in-react-router-4

Answer (score 1):

The hash should be added to the link or simply read from the URL, i.e. the `location` object, instead specified on the `Route` component's `path` prop. Adding it to the `path` will break route path matching.

```
<Route path="/mypage" element={<MyPage />} />
```

`react-router-dom@6` doesn't handle linking directly to hash-tags in the document, and at the moment the best library out there for doing this in previous versions of RRD, [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) has yet to update to support RRDv6.

The `MyPage` component could use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `location.hash`, query the DOM, and attempt to scroll that element into view.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const MyPage = () => {
  const { hash } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.querySelector(hash);
    if (el) {
      el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto" });
    }
  }, [hash]);

  return (
    <>
      ... content ...
      <div id="c">This is the content I'm interested in</div>
      ... more content ...
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-navigate-to-a-html-tag-inside-a-component]

Comment: thank you , i resolved the issue by using the library of (react-router-hash-link) you 've suggested and it worked

Comment: @supercode Wow, really?! I'm a little surprised. If you don't mind could you create a small [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this working? I'd love to see that.

Comment: its quite easy just installed the library via npm ,  imported the HashLink from it and just replaced "Link" that comes with react-router-dom to the  "HashLink" like this :                                                                                                   
 <HashLink  to="/mypage#section">
                go to the section in my page
  </HashLink>  ........ and it navigates to page and scroll directly into the html tag with that id  (#section) . thank you sir for your help

Comment: @supercode I see. This is very interesting. I wonder if something changed on the RRD side. I have some investigating to do now. Thanks for the feedback.